# Upload File: user to server1 to server2

Tags: php, upload, ftp, server

is it possible to upload a file to server2 using server1?

the visitor go to: mywebsite.com **(server1)**
then he upload a file to **server1** and the server1 automatically upload that file to **server2** ??

or simply is it possible to the user to upload a file to server2 using server1 **as a proxy**, because server2 is only accessable from server1

would `ftp` be helpful or is there another better solution?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you can use ftp through your upload script. I dont suggest making server 1 a proxy, that would just add more complication.

Ref: [FTP Uploader using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725215/ftp-uploader-using-php)

---

Another method would be sending file through curl to the script on server 2 more like api.

Ref: [CURL PHP send image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433542/curl-php-send-image)